# How to create text style with multiple offset fill colours

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, typography

Can anyone show me how to recreate something like this:

[image: new order album sleeve]

Comment: can any one tell me the name of the base font used please? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple to create in any application. You haven't specified what software you are using, but the following works in Illustrator and could easily be applied to Photoshop too:

- Create your text
- Duplicate it so that you have three copies
- Offset these copies by an appropriate amount
- Colour one yellow, one cyan and    one magenta
- Set the opacity blend mode of all three to Multiply
- Done

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Alternative answer, inspired by @Cai's comment: I've left this as a separate answer because it might be a bit of a mind bender for less experienced users...

In Illustrator, you can add multiple fills to the same text object and offset those fills from each other using the Transform effect under fx.

The result looks something like this:

[image]

The advantage of this approach is that it is just one text object and it stays live.

Answer (score 3):

1. Type out text 3 times with different colors.
2. Set the blending mode for all 3 sets of text to Multiply.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I've managed to recreate in Illustrator as per instructions above, original is top, my version at the bottom.

However I don't seem to have the darker elements of the original even though I used the colour picker to match the original colours. Any idea how I can get the darkest level darker?

Thanks

Comment: I'm betting you only have to switch colour mode of the document from CMYK to RGB - that should do it.

Comment: Bear in mind, that you've taken up an "answer" for a comment / re-question - and that's really a big no-no.